# How can I catch an interrupted java process in Scala

Tags: java, scala, exception

So, inside my Scala program, I run some Java programs using Scala's process package. Sometimes those Java programs are terminated due to an error. And when that happens they exit with some message, including the stack trace. Now, my question is how can I catch those errors as exceptions. If I simply use `catch { case e: Exception => ... }`, those errors are not caught. I though about using `RunTimeException` or `InterruptedException`, but wouldn't `Exception` include those anyway? So, I thought that wouldn't still solve the problem.

By the way, I launch those programs using something like shown below.

```
"java -jar programsName parameters ...".!
```

Comment: Add the code of how you launch those processes

Comment: @laughedelic: Yes, added that.

Comment: No, you didn't. You only have a string there that shows the command line you are executing. You are **not all showing** the scala code that you are using to invoke java with those arguments.

Comment: @GhostCat: Because I don't want to show that code :).

Comment: Ever heard of creating http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ??? You don't exactly look like some newbie who needs education about that. You do not need to show us your highly confidential production code ...

Comment: @pythonic even if your code is super secret, you should make a minimal example to give some context for your question.

Comment: @pythonic How do you want us to help you when we don't know what you have done? You can create a minimal example that shows your problem. That example does not have to contain the proprietary code that you don't want to show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run it with the [`!!`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder@!!:String) method instead, it will return the output or throw an exception in case of failure as you expect:

> Starts the process represented by this builder, blocks until it exits, and returns the output as a String. Standard error is sent to the console. **If the exit code is non-zero, an exception is thrown**.

While the `!` method just returns the exit code.

Comment: Really? OK, I will try that and see if that works. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't get the intonation of this comment. Is that you don't believe the quoted (and linked) documentation or something else?

Comment: No, I believe you. I just wanna try it to be sure :).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a blog that describes what you are trying to do [Alvin Alexander's Blog](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-execute-exec-external-system-commands-in-scala).

In the **second example** you can see that the result of your call will be and `int`.
Now all you have to do, is a check wether it is 0. A programm that terminates unexpected should / will give a `non-zero exit code`!

There are a some exit codes that have a predefined meanings (at least for UNIX systems). Have a look [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).

I hope this will help you with your task.

PS: Should you have access to the java code, you can also integrate it into your project! Scala can directly call java code and wok with it (although you might need to transform java collections to scala collections).

Comment: That would be a nice way to check too. Never thought about it before :).